# Book about a kid who's invited to a magic school and is hunted by werewolves

Tags: story-identification

Sometime during my early teens (I think) I read a book about a young kid who got invited to some magic school. There was also a heavy focus on him being hunted by werewolves.

I unfortunately don't remember much from it, just that I really enjoyed it. Here's what I can remember, but I don't know how accurate it is:

- Before he even got to the school (maybe even before he got the invitation?) he had his first contact with a werewolf.
- I also remember some kind of simulation (possibly for training), in which the werewolves also show up. This might have been near the end of the book.
- The werewolves were part of some ancient organization (might have been in hiding for a long time and only now surfacing again).
- The magic didn't involve wands or shouting spells, but was more something that they could control with their mind.
- I read it about 10-15 years ago, but I have no idea how old the book was at that point.
- If I recall correctly, the book was about the size of a Harry Potter book.
- It might have been a series, but I'm not sure about that. I only read 1 book.
- I read it in Dutch, but I have no idea what the original language is.

Comment: Do you remember any details about the cover of the book? Any of the artwork that may have been on it?

Comment: @Edlothiad Unfortunately I do not remember anything from the cover. It might have been dark (maybe with red), but I really can't say if that's just something that came to mind or is specifically linked to this book.